# Ho to pass a @selector from one method parameter to another?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to do this but 'performSelectorOnMainThread:recievedDataSelector' throws an unrecognised selector exception.

```
-(void)updateStatus
{   
    [self makeRequest:@"http://someplace.com/blah.php"
       onRecievedData:@selector(updateStatusRecievedData)];
}


-(void)makeRequest:(NSString *)url onRecievedData:(SEL) recievedDataSelector
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:_operationQueue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
             [self performSelectorOnMainThread:recievedDataSelector
                                    withObject:data
                                 waitUntilDone:YES];
     }
}

(void)updateReceivedData:(NSData *) data
{
    NSLog(@"[updateReceivedData]");
}
```

Comment: No, not again, please! **Read** and **understand** and you suddenly won't need to ask stuff like this. [All typo questions should be closed.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167342/close-all-the-typo-questions)

Comment: And to think I already went through this a week ago. I just assumed passing selectors would be non trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss '**`:`**' to `updateStatusRecievedData` method

```
-(void)updateStatus
{   
    [self makeRequest:@"http://someplace.com/blah.php"
       onRecievedData:@selector(updateStatusRecievedData:)];
}
```